# XFBML Cross Scripting and PCI Validation

Tags: facebook, user-interface, xss, xfbml

Are you aware of any cross scripting issues that may occur as a result of using XFBML facebook buttons on my website? Want to make sure that I don’t run foul of PCI validation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be absolutely sure, you should contact your PCI Evaluator and ask him the question.

However, it should be noted that widgets from Social Networks (Such as Facebook, Twitter, Google+) are served using an iFrame using HTTPS. Therefore you're backend is never exposed to the scripts, and unless you decided to insert CreditCard Information in the URL for those widgets, you should be pretty safe.